# Uploading photo doesn't work on a Cordova app on iPhone6

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, webview

I am running into an issue with just iPhone 6 and 6 Plus running on iOS 8.2 or higher, after taking a photo, I am unable to upload a photo to the Webview.

The app is built using Cordova 5.0.0. It works fine on iPhone 5.

Thanks for any help.

JS

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(e) {
        console.log("TakePhoto:" + JSON.stringify(e));
        that.__onMediaSuccess(e, FORMAT_IMAGE, onError);
    },
    onError, {
        quality: 75,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        targetWidth: 800,
        targetHeight: 800,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
        correctOrientation: true
    });
```

Comment: just updated with code used to take picture from the js file